# How can I set the current date to an attribute in XAML (WinRT)?

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have a `MaxValue` attribute on a control in a `DataTemplate` that I just want to set to the current date. I really don't want a property on my object bound to the data template returning the current date since such a property doesn't logically belong there.
How can this be done in WinRT which doesn't have support for `x:Static`?

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="DateTimeTemplate">
...
        <Input:RadDatePicker MaxValue="{Binding ?}"/>
...
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by setting `MaxValue` in code behind like so:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="DateTimeTemplate">
...
    <Input:RadDatePicker Loaded = "DatePickerLoaded"/>
...
</DataTemplate>

//Event handler
private void DatePickerLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ((DatePicker)sender).MaxValue = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```